# Get GPU Information in linux C

Tags: linux, gpu, bios

Is there any library in C for Linux to get gpu information for example BIOS Verison DigitalID...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not a library, and not as detailed information as BIOS version, there is `lshw` which at least is able to identify manufacturer and model, e.g.

my current pc:

```
       *-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GeForce 8500 GT
            vendor: nVidia Corporation
            ...
```

older pc

```
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I misread CPU for gpu, sorry.  Perhaps exec gfxinfo?